# differential Op-Amp oscillation

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillation

I have used the THS4151 op-amp to create a circuit that takes two inputs and subtract them to give an output. Below is the schematic for the circuit:

[image]

R1 is where I will input a 1 MHz, 2V sinusoidal signal, and R6 is where the other input signal should come from. In this case, I grounded that input. Below is a picture of the input signal for R1:
[image]

My problem is when I try to power the op-amp, It will oscillate, and the input signal will look like:
[image]
And the output signal will look like:
[image]
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Is your ground potential floating, or is it properly fixed in the middle between your +12 V and -12V?

Comment: I'm using a virtual ground. I'm using a linear power supply that has only one channel. To get the negative voltage, I had to use two 10 k ohm resistors in series to form a voltage divider.

Comment: I have my doubts about C3 and C4, why are these needed? They might be introducing the pole that's giving you the oscillation. Also you should add supply decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Add some major decoupling from that virtual GND to both supply rails. Like 100uF + 100nF to each rail.